# Atomic.h force_clock

Tags: android, linux, kernel, atomic

I'm trying to understand some code in android kernel (specific to a chipset)

So I made a diff with another kernel

And I found some stuff I can't understand like this one in atomic.h :

```
#if defined(FORCE_CACHED_LOCK)
#if !defined(force_clock)
extern void __force_clock(u32 l);
#define force_clock __force_clock
#endif
#else
#define force_clock(l)
#endif
```

And at every function of atomic.h

force_clock((u32)v) or force_clock((u32)ptr) or force_clock((u32)*addr) (depends on function itself if it uses ptr or *addr or v)

I'm sure FORCE_CACHED_LOCK is not set so what happens ? Is this code usefull ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was simple...

I just need to check if FORCE_CACHED_LOCK is really not set, I have to be sure so i put :

```
#if defined(FORCE_CACHED_LOCK)
#error zonk
#if !defined(force_clock)
```

So build should fails if FORCE_CACHED_LOCK is set by some magic stuff... If not set, the force_clock is useless so I can remove it :)

Credits for derRichard @ OFTC IRC